# Is there is a way for use wix navigation expo react native

Tags: react-native

### How to implement the wix navigation? ## .

**I am want to use wix navigation in expo react native**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wix uses native features to navigate for better performance. You need native project to use wix. You cannot use wix with expo project. Read this [installation guide](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing), they don't have expo support and will likely never be.